# Como criar um vector2 em C?

Tags: c, variáveis, classes-abstratas

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu criar uma classe, para armazenar 2 variáveis, por exemplo, um Vector2, onde eu instanciaria e usaria assim:

```
Vector2 tile;
int posX, posY;
posX = tile.x;
posY = tile.Y;
```

ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 5):

Em C, com `struct` (C nao tem `class`), faz assim

```
/* define struct Vector2 com dois elementos */
struct Vector2 {
    int x;
    int y;
};

/* define tile como uma variavel pertencente ao tipo struct Vector2 */
struct Vector2 tile;

/* atribui valores aos membros de tile */
tile.x = 42;
tile.y = -1;
```

Comment: Ha quem goste de usar `typedef` para especificar outro nome para o tipo sem ter que escrever `struct`. Eu nao vejo grande vantagem nisso (escrever `struct` nao custa e pode tornar o programa mais legivel), por isso nao uso o `typedef` com esse efeito.

Answer (score 0):

Em C, não utiliza-se Classes, como é feito em C++.
Quando desejamos armazenar dados de tipos diferentes, utilizamos `struct`:

```
struct estrutura {
    int nBase;
    int nAltura;
    double fArea; };
```

e aí podemos criar estruturas do tipo `struct estrutura`:

```
 estrutura triangulo1;
 estrutura retangulo1;
```

e acessar seus elementos independentes entre si:

```
triangulo1.nBase = 10;
triangulo1.nAltura = 5;
triangulo1.fArea = triangulo1.nBase * triangulo1.nAltura / 2.0;
// triangulo1.fArea terá valor de 7.5

retangulo1.nBase = 7;
retangulo1.nAltura = 3;
retangulo1.fArea = nBase * nAltura;
// retangulo1.fArea terá valor de 21.0
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Hmmm ... o tipo `estrutura` nao existe sem um `typedef`. O comentario relativo a fArea tem um valor diferente de 25.